# Flexbox alternative for IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, flexbox

I have developed a website with Chrome initially (easiest to design for) but now am getting to IE support model.

That being said, I started with IE11 and made the necessary changes for the quirky differences between IE & Chrome.  But now I am stepping down the IE versions. I was able to get 90% of the webpages to display correctly with CSS for IE10.  But now most of the CSS elements that I have for these two browsers, are for the most part irrelevant for IE9.

I would like to keep from needing to have multiple browser specific style sheets, if possible.

First problems is converting IE10+ implementation of the flexbox model of CSS.

Current Implementation for the flexbox container:

```
div#navContainer{
    display: flex; //Current browsers (IE11, Chrome, etc)
    display: -ms-flexbox; //IE10 implementation
}

div#TeamsSection {
    text-align: center;
}

div.NavSection {
    margin: 0px 7px;
    padding: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
}

div#teams {
    margin: 0px;

    select {
        margin: 0px;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="navContainer" class="float-left">
    <div id="LogoSection" class="NavSection">
        <div id="Logo">
            <img src="Images/Logo.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="TeamsSection" class="NavSection">
        <label>Select a Team:</label><br />
        <div id="teams"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="UserSection" class="NavSection hidden">
        <label>Select a User:</label><br />
        <div id="requestor"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know IE9 does not implement Flexbox, so please don't insult the research I have already done. I need an equivalent implementation that will allow me to change the HTML as little as possible.

Comment: you do not say how you use the flex propertie, display:table & table-cell could be a fallback where else it would be playing with layout ant text-align. display:flex; on it's own doesn't give enough to advise you for specific fallbacks

Comment: Well, the `#navContainer` element is the one that is causing the out of flow problem for IE9.  I posted the HTML and extended children CSS styles.  `#teams` & `#requestor` are filled by Mustache from templates.  Again the problem is really with the `#navContainer`, as IE10+ and Chrome it works as expected.  Its IE9, I need to try and get a proper implementation for.

Comment: You should check out [Flexie.js](http://flexiejs.com/).

Comment: This is not an answer to flexbox on IE9, but if you're adding vendor prefixes to support IE10 consider using Autoprefixer. It really makes it easy.

Comment: Use autoprefixer.

Answer (score 78):

Use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/#flexbox) to detect whether flex capabilities are present, and provide fallback styles where necessary. Modernizr will add classes like `flexbox`, `no-flexbox`, and `flexbox-legacy` to the html element, so in your styles you can use:

```
    .container {
        display: flex;
    }
    .no-flexbox .container {
        display: table-cell;
    }
```

I highly recommend reading through Zoe Gillenwater's ([@zomigi](https://twitter.com/zomigi)) presentations on the subject, particularly [Leveling Up With Flexbox (Smart Web Conference - September 2014)](http://www.slideshare.net/zomigi/leveling-up-with-flexbox-smartwebconf140923)

- slide 21: horizontal navigation spacing > `display: inline-block;`
- slide 62: pinning elements without flexbox > `display: table-cell;`
- slide 70,71: aligning forms fallbacks
- slide 88,91: example with and without flex order

Also, in her presentation [CSS3 Layout](http://www.slideshare.net/zomigi/css3-layout), there are a few good sideby side previews of layouts with and without flexbox:

- slide 73: Using inline-block with flexbox: horizontal form
- slide 79: Using inline-block with flexbox: horizontal navigation

Some of takeaways for me:

- browser support ie10+ is pretty good [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)
- use [auto-prefixr](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) to handle browser prefixes
- use modernizr to provide fallbacks
- "flexbox is not all or nothing" @zomigi

Comment: .container {
        display: flex;
        display: table-cell;
    }

Comment: I think it should be `.container {display: table-cell; display: flex;}`

Answer (score 46):

I like the  above answer but you don't have to use modernizr.
You could simply use table layout for ie9 and flexbox for others.

```css
.container {
    display: table-cell; // ie9
    display: flex;       // others
}
```

Comment: nice! I guess there may be some edge cases where `flexbox-legacy` browsers render slightly differently.. autoprefixer is still handy!

Comment: This doesn't work. It's the child elements of `.container` that need to be positioned inline, not `.container` itself.

Comment: Add the above code to the child elements if that is what you need.

Comment: I like to create a mixin so that another dev, but most likely myself, do not forget to add in the fallback:

`@mixin display-flex() {display: table-cell; display: flex;}`

Answer (score 9):

One year later, this solution, using JavaScript to adjust the layout in older browsers, seems interesting => https://github.com/10up/flexibility

Almost 2000 stars on Github but the last commit was 3 months ago, I don't know if it still actively maintained.

Comment: quality utility does not need alot of active changes.  Google's BootStrap seems to also provide the functionality we have all struggled with.

Comment: Actually it's Twitter Bootstrap. Just sayin'. ;)

Comment: Technicalities, they all come from the same branch of the tree ;)