# Whats the best alternative for display:flex for the Inernet explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

With display:flex , we can make divs float next to each other. However display:flex does not work in IE. So how to create a similar effect in IE in the simplest possible way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question may have already been answered in the following post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28709421/3943441

If this doesn't help out, please clarify what is different in your problem and I would be glad to continue helping in your search for a solution.