# Split Table Row(s) for smaller screens

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I have a table with fixed width of 960px with 5 columns.

When I view in a mobile device, I'd like to make columns 3,4,5
to appear as if it is on the next row.

Is there any way the CSS can break a row so it looks this, but 
still keep the original HTML code?

Comment: You mean column will be a look like row in mobile device..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use FlexBox:

```css
.flexParent{
  display: flex;
}

.flexChild{
  width: 20%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
   .flexParent{
      flex-wrap: wrap; 
   }
   .flexChild{
     width: 50%;
   }
   .wrap{
     width: 30%;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="flexParent">
  <div class="flexChild">1</div>
  <div class="flexChild">2</div>
  <div class="flexChild wrap">3</div>
  <div class="flexChild wrap">4</div>
  <div class="flexChild wrap">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, the example used worked as expected in FF and Chrome, is there something that can still support IE9 as well?

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371408/flexbox-alternative-for-ie9

Answer (score 1):

you can try CSS media query, example (adjust your own width)

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* For desktop: */
    .col-1 {width: 20%;}
    .col-2 {width: 20%;}
    .col-3 {width: 20%;}
    .col-4 {width: 20%;}
    .col-5 {width: 20%;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    /* For mobile: */
    .col-1 {width: 50%;}
    .col-2 {width: 50%;}
    .col-3 {width: 30%;}
    .col-4 {width: 30%;}
    .col-5 {width: 30%;}
}
```

**more examples** [here](http://%20%20%20%20@media%20only%20screen%20and%20(min-width:%20768px)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20/*%20For%20desktop:%20*/%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.col-1%20%7Bwidth:%208.33%25;%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.col-2%20%7Bwidth:%2016.66%25;%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.col-3%20%7Bwidth:%2025%25;%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.col-4%20%7Bwidth:%2033.33%25;%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.col-5%20%7Bwidth:%2041.66%25;%7D%20%20%20%20%20%7D)