# Firefox ignoring height: 100%

Tags: html, css

I have the following snippet that works in chrome and explorer, however I can't seem to get firefox to make the left bar `.leftpanel` stretch to the full height of the parent `.viewer`

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dq75u3ok/)

**Snippet**

```css
html,
body {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.fullscreen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: pink;
  display: table;
  z-index: 1;
}
.centeralign {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2em;
}
.viewer {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 1em;
  min-height: 35.45em;
}
.leftpanel {
  width: 15em;
  /*Alter depending on how much space this takes*/
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.leftpanel .slide {
  width: 15em;
  height: 9.706em;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background-color: red;
}
.leftpanel .comments_container {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 14em;
  width: 15em;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul class="fullscreen">
  <li class="centeralign">
    <ul class="viewer">
      <li class="leftpanel">
        <ul class="slide">
          <li class="slide_image">
          </li>
          <li class="slide_menu">
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="slide">
          <li class="slide_image">
          </li>
          <li class="slide_menu">
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="comments_container">
          <li class="comments">
            <span class="comment">Test</span>
          </li>
          <li class="new_comment">
            <form action="new_comment.php">
              <input type="text" name="comment" />
              <input type="submit" name="Send" />
            </form>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="viewport">
      </li>
      <li class="close">
        X
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried a reset? If not, czech out https://github.com/murtaugh/HTML5-Reset

Comment: I actually have a reset! But alas it does not solve the problem

Comment: Although I admit that is not the reset I'm running

Comment: Why does your `comments_container` need to be absolute? Setting it to static, and leaving out relative on leftpanel solves the problem. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dq75u3ok/2/). Also, I'm seeing too much "table"-fiddling. There's no point in "not using divs, but setting all divs to behave as tables". Try to work with the actual positioning tools you have. In your case especially float, clearing your floats and for fluid re-sizing possibly flex.

Comment: I made `comments_container` absolute because I need to to stick to the bottom of the `leftpanel` container and then a javascript function will adjust its height to take up the slack to the `slide` elements. This is necessary because the height and width of the `viewer` element will also be adjusted through javascript depending on the image loaded into the `viewport` element

Comment: Did you try to remove the `min-height: 35.45em;` from `.viewer` ?

Comment: That appears to work - But why?

Comment: Your code is "over-complicated".  One thing i've learnt being a frontend developer is that if you mix absolute/relative positioning, display: inline-block/table/table-cell and mix in floats, something unexpected will happen.

Comment: Good advice, man. I'll try to simplify it a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your question has already been answered, here is the 'general' solution:

`.clearfix:before,`

`.clearfix:after     { content: ''; display: table }`

`.clearfix:after     { clear: both }`

Your `viewer` class needs the well known 'clearfix' added in the HTML, search google for a proper explanation on that. Modify your viewer HTML `<ul class="viewer clearfix">` and add the class to your **global** CSS (for general use) and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks man! I've changed my accepted answer because your solution worked better for me and let me keep the min-height!

Comment: Always ready to..., well you know. It's a nasty little issue that keeps returning, be aware of that! Digg into flexbox, it is well worth your time.

Comment: Check my [codepen](http://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/pJpMrB), not the easiest example, but very eleborate (and responsive)...

Comment: I miss the `float` attribute on the  `leftpanel`, floating always causes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

At first sight, your issue is you are setting a big `min-height` to your parent `.viewer`, so just remove it because you already have set a `height` as `90%` within another parent.

```css
html,
body {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.fullscreen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: pink;
  display: table;
  z-index: 1;
}
.centeralign {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2em;
}
.viewer {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 1em;
  /* min-height: 35.45em; remove this line */
}
.leftpanel {
  width: 15em;
  /*Alter depending on how much space this takes*/
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.leftpanel .slide {
  width: 15em;
  height: 9.706em;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background-color: red;
}
.leftpanel .comments_container {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 14em;
  width: 15em;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul class="fullscreen">
  <li class="centeralign">
    <ul class="viewer">
      <li class="leftpanel">
        <ul class="slide">
          <li class="slide_image">
          </li>
          <li class="slide_menu">
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="slide">
          <li class="slide_image">
          </li>
          <li class="slide_menu">
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="comments_container">
          <li class="comments">
            <span class="comment">Test</span>
          </li>
          <li class="new_comment">
            <form action="new_comment.php">
              <input type="text" name="comment" />
              <input type="submit" name="Send" />
            </form>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="viewport">
      </li>
      <li class="close">
        X
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Might not setting a minimum height cause the child elements to break out of `viewer` when the browser is resized to too-small a height?

Comment: I guess I didn't understand your question but I'll try to explain to you..
your parent `.viewer` has a (min)`height` of 5000px (example) but your child `leftpanel` only using 1000px of `height`  therefore  is till 4000px down from the end of child to the end of parent So if you remove the `min-height` the end of the child will end next to the end of the parent `height`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't tell you why firefox is doing this or what is causing this, however, I can give you a possible fix for this problem, which doesn't include that much of a change in your code.

The solution is simple, use `display:flex` *instead of* `display:inline-block` on your `.viewer` element and give the *children*, in this case the `.leftpanel` element the property `align-items:stretch`

To read more on this check out either [this css-tricks guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or [this MDN guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

Your updated code will look like this:

**HTML:** Nothing changed.

**CSS:**

```
.viewer {
    text-align: left;
    display: flex; /* changed the display to flex */
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
    padding: 1em;
    min-height: 35.45em;
}

.leftpanel {
    width: 15em; /*Alter depending on how much space this takes*/
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: yellow;
    align-items: stretch; /* Added the align-items property */
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wr6eqeqc/1/)**

Hope this helps!

Comment: What happens with older versions of internet explorer when you use flex? I haven't really read up on it because it sounds like it wouldn't work on versions below IE11. Although that appears to only affect around 2% of users right now...

Comment: @tomc You can use modernizr to detect whether flex capabilities are present, and provide fallback styles where necessary. Modernizr will add classes like `flexbox`, `no-flexbox`, and `flexbox-legacy` to the html element, read more about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371408/flexbox-alternative-for-ie9) and [here (modernizr)](https://modernizr.com/)

Comment: @tomc Ofcourse, this is only if you really *have to* reach that last 2%