# I'm having issues with a fluid layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fluid-layout

I'm trying to have a fluid design that can be used for mobile support. I can make it zoom in and resize the divs correctly but when i try to add fixed positions for the chat window and chat message input box, it doesn't work. Div 2 and Div 3 bunches up to Div 1 and if i change the wrapper to fixed position, the automatic resizing stops working completely.

Here's how the design works:
[image]

Is it possible to achieve this without using javascript, and if not, what can be done to achieve my goal?

EDIT: Removed Code since it is no longer relevant.

The solution has been found!
- Going to use Flexbox (does exactly what I would want plus it does more), thanks Jason!
- If I need to add IE9 support, I'll use Modernizr as shown in the comments. Thanks XKCD149!

Comment: don't use floats. use flexbox!

Comment: This is the first time i hear about flexbox, I'll take a look right now! :D

Comment: Stay away from inline styling and check out a framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) if you are having trouble.

Comment: I'm enjoying flexbox already (great find) but it's not IE9 compatible unfortunately and I don't want to use the bloated boostrap. I don't use much inline styling, it's mainly to explain what's going on here.  I'm hoping to avoid using any third party plugin if at all possible.

Comment: don't worry about supporting IE9

Comment: Modernizr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371408/flexbox-alternative-for-ie9

Comment: Color me impressed, I'm sold on the flexbox solution now. :) Thanks everyone for your help! IE9 has less than 1% of users anyhow and Modernizr is a great way to alleviate the pain of dealing with IE9 if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you'd accomplish the above layout using flexbox:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

nav {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
}

article {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

footer {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>My Nav</nav>
  <article>My Main Body</article>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still running through the tutorials and your answers were great! Honestly flexible layouts were getting really difficult using the old fashion way.

Comment: glad i could help :)