# How to make a div take the remaining height without knowing the height?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 2 elements inside **.container**, that is **.header** and **.overflowElem**.

I want **.overflowElem** to take the remaining height of the **.container**, and it should be overflow-y: auto.

HTML

```
<div class="box">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="header">
      <h1>HEADER</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="overflowElem">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ITEM 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ITEM 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ITEM 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

All of this HTML is injected using jQuery's ajax, like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "include/get_list.php",
    data: params
}).done(function(data) {
    var container = $("<div></div>")
        .attr("class", "container")
        .html(data)
        .hide()
        .appendTo(box);

}).fail(function() {
    alert("Error.");

}).always(function(data) {

})
```

Notice how **var container** is hidden at the time of initialization

CSS :

```
div.box {
  width: 700px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 45px 20px 20px;
}

div.container {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #bbb;
}

div.header {
  background-color: red;
  /* HEIGHT in pixels is UNKNOWN */
}

div.overflowElem {
  overflow-y: auto;
  /*
  CANNOT USE THIS BECAUSE i DON'T know the height of .header
  height: calc(100% - height of .header in pixels);*/
}
```

jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/n4z02gL2/1/

Now, i could add a height to **.header** and calculate the height of **.overflowElem** using calc() and bingo!

BUT, because all of the HTML is inserted using jQuery's ajax, and it's hidden at the moment of initialization, i don't tknowthe height neither i cant get it using ajax because the container is hidden

So, what is the solution? Any ideas, tips, tricks, hacks...
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using flexbox all you have to do is update your `div.container` rule (without prefixing, for brevity).

```
div.container {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #bbb;

  // add these properties here
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Granted, this is assuming your browser support allows you to use flexbox. [CSS Tricks has a great write-up of flexbox here.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: nice solution! according to "ca i use" website, support is ok, except for IE (what a surprise)...http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: @Marco not that I've had to, but poking around I found there's some decent fallback options. [Using modernizr is probably a good choice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371408/flexbox-alternative-for-ie9)

Comment: @Marco which IE ??  https://jsfiddle.net/n4z02gL2/2/ ( looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098042/fill-remaining-vertical-space-with-css-using-displayflex/25098486 )