# display: flex property not rendering properly in Internet Explorer properly

Tags: html, css, flexbox, display

I am creating a layout for my application and its with fixed header , Footer and Left Menu. The content is scrolling while other are fixed. I have no problem in making the layout. When I am trying to give the `display:flex` to my `.center-container` class , it is not rendering properly in IE-10.

Below is my CSS

```
.center-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Also the html is big and I have created [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/tiwariliferocks/uwmq2aqb/) for that.

Comment: Flexbox support in IE is very buggy. If you must support IE you should [find an alternative.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371408/flexbox-alternative-for-ie9) Should be ok on Edge though.

Comment: I tried the alternative and still have same behavior

Answer (score 1):

According to MDN, display flex is only supported in IE 10 with the -ms vendor prefix:

`display: -ms-flex;`

[Display Flex on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/flex#Browser_compatibility)