# Responsive search field layout while avoiding position absolute

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have this specific layout problem.

Where I want to get 3 containers in one row, where left and right are with fixed width and middle one is responsive. And inside there is a input field and submit button, where the input field is the responsive one. Example:

[image: How I would like it to look]

What I tried to do, is to use a div-wrapper, that contains the padding and fake-styling for input. And then inside this wrapper there is `width: 100%;` input field. Sadly, my approach is not working no matter how hard I tried:

```css
#general_before {display: inline-block; background: rgba(34, 43, 34, 0.5); width: 100px;}
#general_wrapper {display: inline-block; width: 100%; border: 2px solid black;}
#field_wrapper {padding: 5px; background: rgba(45, 65, 78, 0.5);}
#field {width: 100%;}
#submit {float: right;}
#general_after {display: inline-block; background: rgba(45, 87, 56, 0.5); width: 100px;}
```

```html
<div id="general_before">BEFORE</div>
<div id="general_wrapper">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="GO" />
<div id="field_wrapper"><input id="field" type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter your search term here.." value="" /></div>
</div>
<div id="general_after">AFTER</div>
```

I don't even have a solution for the 3 containers in a row, except using position absolute `position: absolute; left: 200px; right: 200;` on the middle container. But this feels wrong approach to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Flexboxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```css
#container, #general_wrapper {display: flex;}
#general_wrapper, #field_wrapper {flex-grow: 1;}
#field { width: 100%;}
```

```html
<div id="general_before">BEFORE</div>
<div id="general_wrapper">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="GO" />
<div id="field_wrapper"><input id="field" type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter your search term here.." value="" /></div>
</div>
<div id="general_after">AFTER</div>
```

#### Update for IE support

```css
#container , #general_wrapper { display: table; width: 100%;}
#general_before, #general_after, #submit, #field_wrapper { display: table-cell;}

#field_wrapper, #field_wrapper input  { width: 100%;}
#general_before, #general_after, #submit {width: 100px;}
```

```html
<div id="general_before">BEFORE</div>
<div id="general_wrapper">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="GO" />
<div id="field_wrapper"><input id="field" type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter your search term here.." value="" /></div>
</div>
<div id="general_after">AFTER</div>
```

Comment: Interesting reading. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox But I need that partial IE support as well. Looking for a more oldschool solution, or at least compatibility.

Comment: For IE support take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371408/flexbox-alternative-for-ie9#answer-28709421

Comment: I can probably cook up a solution, that uses less code the modernizer. But I want it to be dry to be bone, without any extras. No jQuery, no extra libs.

Comment: The answer does not only recommend to use modernizer, but also proposes the fallback css solution (use of `display: table-*`, etc.). I updated my answer with a valid solution.

Comment: @KalleH.Väravas: Please mark this answer as the accepted one if it helped you. Otherwise it would be nice if you'd explain why it did not help you.

Comment: Hello, it did help me with the idea of using display table. Did not think about it at all. I forgot to accept it, because the snippet itself and provided code was irrelevant, because it did not produce the result looked for.