# Responsive layout with 3 DIVS possible in IE9?

Tags: html, css, layout, internet-explorer-9

Is it possible to make this work in IE9?

example1: https://jsfiddle.net/ydv01r9e/5/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="b">b<br>b</div>
   <div class="a">a</div>
   <div class="c">c</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .a, .b, .c {
  width: 50%;
}

.b {
  float: left;
}

.a, .c{
  float: right;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .a, .b, .c {
    width: auto;
  }
  .a {
    order: 1;
  }
  .b {
    order: 2;
  }
  .c {
    order: 3;
  }
}

.a {
  background: red;
}

.b {
  background: blue;
}

.c {
  background: yellow;
}
```

or

example2: http://jsfiddle.net/eLq0770h/14/ , but this one is not responsive. I need 3x1 layout for mobile: red div on the top, blue in the middle and green on the bottom, like in example1.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a site like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/#flexbox) to see compatibility issues for flex-box.

You're most likely going to need to use a system like display:table-cell; for correct formatting in ie9.

[Here's another question for a similar issue with more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371408/flexbox-alternative-for-ie9)